# Draw view as line

Tags: ios

I have some problem when :

1 - I make a simple custom UIView(WSSLine)  with start and end points, width = lenght(startPoint, endPoint), height = 4. A point is class WSSPoint with x and y.
File WSSLine.m

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
      startPoint:(WSSPoint *)start endPoint:(WSSPoint*)end {
    float l = [start getLenghtWithOtherPoint:end];
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake([start x],
                                       [start y],
                                       l , [Application getLineWidth]) ];
    if (self) {
        UIColor* bg = [UIColor colorWithRed:225 green:225 blue:0 alpha:1];
        self.backgroundColor = bg;
        [self setLenght:l];

        float t =[start getAngleWithOtherPoint:end];
        self.currentAngle = t;
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, t);
    }
}
```

In file WSSPoint.m function getAngleWithOtherPoint:

```
- (float) getAngleWithOtherPoint: (WSSPoint*) otherPoint {
    float a = ([otherPoint y] - [self y])/([otherPoint x] - [self x]);
    float arcCos = 1/(sqrtf(1 + a*a));
    return acosf(arcCos);
}
```

and function getLenghtWithOtherPoint

```
- (float) getLenghtWithOtherPoint:(WSSPoint *)otherPoint {
    float lenghtX = [otherPoint x] - [self x];
    float lenghtY = [otherPoint y] - [self y];

    return sqrtf(lenghtX*lenghtX + lenghtY*lenghtY);
}
```

I've tried more ways to draw this view, using anchor or view.layer, but it is not correct for all cases. Please help me find the correct way to draw it.

2- I want make resize on view but endPoint not change position.  What should I do?

Thank a lot

Comment: What's up with all the *'s in initWithFrame?  What's up with the first parameter to getAngleWith_OX?

Comment: Use CGFloat not float.

Comment: @uchuugaka which will make zero difference as CGFloat is a typedef for float on iOS.

Comment: I never said it would make a difference here, but it's probably a good habit. Are you sure that's true for 64 bit as well? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html  As with the OS X conversion before, the point of NSInteger, NSUInteger and CGFloat is to let you let the compiler choose the right one. Just good habits.